# Java String.matches() regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to use the matches() function to check a user-entered password for certain conditions

"Contains six alphanumeric characters, at least one letter and one number"

Here is my current condition for checking for alphanumeric characters

`pword.matches("([[a-zA-Z]&&0-9])*")`

unfortunately in example using "rrrrZZ1" as the password this condition still returns false

What would be the correct regular expression? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone else here may prove me wrong, but this is going to be very difficult to do without an excessively complex regular expression.  I'd just use a non-regular expression approach instead.  Set 3 booleans for each of your conditions, loop through the characters and set each boolean as each condition is met, and if all 3 booleans don't equal true, then fail the verification.

You could use something as simple as this:

```
public boolean validatePassword(String password){
    if(password.length() < 6){
        return false;
    }
    boolean foundLetter = false;
    boolean foundNumber = false;
    for(int i=0; i < password.length(); i++){
        char c = password.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isLetter(c)){
            foundLetter = true;
        }else if(Character.isDigit(c)){
            foundNumber = true;
        }else{
            // Isn't alpha-numeric.
            return false;
        }
    }
    return foundLetter && foundNumber;
}
```

Comment: the `matches` function uses booleans, I think my understanding of the matches boolean logic is wrong though. it is very close.  the * character loops through already checking for each condition

Comment: @CQM - no, the `*` character is matching against the previous expression 0 or more times.  (Probably exactly not what you wanted.)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with ziesemer - use a validatePassword() method instead of cramming it into regex.

Much more readable for a developer to maintain.

If you do want to go down the regex path, it is achievable using zero width positive lookaheads.

Contains six characters, at least one letter and one number:

```
^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$
```

I changed your six `alphanumeric characters` to just `characters`.
Supports more complex passwords :)

Great post on the topic:

http://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/

Bookmark this one too:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: I would guess that the `validatePassword()` method will also be better performing than whatever the regular expression pattern will be compiled down to.  :-)  Where a regular expression really works well is when it can be used as a replaceable property - I.E., store a required pattern as a regex in a property file.  I'm just not sure how useful this would be for password validation rules.

Comment: Another bonus for a method() is that it can leave early if a positive outcome is found. With regex, the whole pattern is compiled and matched each time. eg. If you must have a len > 6 pass, and you give it 5 chars, you can bail after a simple length check, which is heaps faster than a regex compile